# maximum height for stove receptacle

Tags: electrical, wiring, stove

I'm installing a stove receptacle on a wall that's partially below grade so the lower half of the wall is masonry, the upper half is normal studs, drywall, etc.   it would be easier to put the receptacle in the upper half of the wall where it might be slightly visible above the top of the stove (I need to measure how high).  The wire would would be coming down from the ceiling. Would this be considered a safety issue?  I'm thinking about grease fires, etc.

I suppose the normal position is more vulnerable to an over flow from a huge pot of water, but the breaker should stop that...

Comment: By that logic, an outlet is more vulnerable to water on the floor. Plenty of dryer and other appliance outlets are in the wall. That said, I'd probably look at a decorative channel or something to make it less conspicuous.

Answer (score 2):

I can almost guaranty you that anything higher than 12-16", and lower than roughly 54", will be no good.

Ranges and ovens typically have very specific places that the receptacle can be placed. For a "standard" residential range down low behind the drawer is typically a good spot.

You can mount it above the backsplash/control panel, but what about mounting it to the floor right at the wall line? More than anything I'd check the documentation that comes with the range to be sure.

This is also assuming an electric range with a 50A plug/receptacle.

Answer (score 0):

Exposed NM wire where prone to damage should be in a protective conduit.  PVC schedule 80, EMT, or MC cable comes to mind.

Appliance cords, however, can float and dangle and take a few brumps as they are tougher.

Comment: The way I want to do it the wires would be in the wall.  The cord/plug would be visible.  Are you saying that I put the cord in conduit?

Comment: My range has a cavity where the plug and excess power cord fit. You might bring the cable down inside the wall to the masonry and then down in conduit or surface channel to the standard height above the floor on the surface of the masonry to a surface mount receptacle.

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: The NM wire is coming down from the wired and would be inside the wall until it meets the masonry bottom.  Only the outlet would be exposed.  If I ran it down the wall I'd need to cover the NM wire where it ran over the masonry wall.  PVC would be easiest.  How well would it take heat?